# How do you call an external web api from CRM Plugin?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm new to CRM development. I'm trying to figure out how to call an external api endpoint from my post-operation create stage. How can I accomplish this?

```
protected void ExecutePostOrderCreate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
    if (localContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
    }

    IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;

    Entity postImageEntity = (context.PostEntityImages != null && context.PostEntityImages.Contains(this.postImageAlias)) ? context.PostEntityImages[this.postImageAlias] : null;

    if (postImageEntity != null)
    {
        ProcessOrderCaseType(postImageEntity, localContext);
    }
}

private void ProcessOrderCaseType(Entity order, LocalPluginContext localContext)
{

    int caseType = GetCaseType(order);

    Boolean caseTypeIsWorkersComp = caseType == (int)MLUtility.CaseTypes.WorkersComp;
    Boolean orderHasEamsCaseMaster = OrderHasCaseMaster(order);

    if (caseTypeIsWorkersComp && !orderHasEamsCaseMaster)
    {
        String caseNumber = GetCaseNumber(order);
        Boolean caseNumberIsValid = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(caseNumber);
        if (caseNumberIsValid)
        {
          **//call api**

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this--This is for CRM Dynamics 2013

Answer (score 0):

This is same like calling api from anywhere else. Only extra step would be merging the extra dll like `Newtonsoft.Json` into main plugin dll before registering in plugin registration tool or gac in server.

[Code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-call-Rest-Service-b0b188df)

```
var uri = new Uri("<external api url>"); 
 
                var request = WebRequest.Create(uri); 
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; 
                request.ContentType = "application/json"; 
                try 
                { 
                    string helloWorldString = ""; 
                    using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
                    { 
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) 
                        { 
                            string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
                            helloWorldString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(tmp); 
                            Debug.Print("I read this string {0}: ", helloWorldString); 
                        } 
                    } 
 
                    var entity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"]; 
                    if (entity.Contains("description")) 
                        entity.Attributes["description"] = helloWorldString; 
                    else 
                        entity.Attributes.Add("description", helloWorldString); 
 
                    //Update Sales Order Entity 
                    if (context.Depth == 1) 
                        service.Update(entity); 
 
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                { 
                    throw; 
                }
```

Comment: Thanks Arun.  I was able to call my webservice and return a response.  However, there is an anomaly.  The issue is that I'm using the CRM Plug-in registration tool.  I created a profile and when debugging, the tool crashes on me.  However, if I use the trace service and add some "bread crumbs", all works okay. Not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: @JeffreyJuarez it should work, not sure. You can post a different question on that topic. If this answer solves your question, upvote/mark it.